# Cant see newly added attribute in product edit page

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I've added a new attribute in

> admin > Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes

but I did not add it to an attribute set as it will not be required on the frontend.

However now I can't see this newly created attribute when I go to edit a (simple) product anywhere?

**Magento 1.9**

Help appreciated, thank you

Comment: Have you assigned that attribute to attribute set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to see newly created attribute in the product edit page in admin panel, you need to go to:

> Catalog > Attributes -> Manage Attribute Sets

then open appropriate attribute set and assign the attribute by dragging it into the attribute group.

Save the attribute set, reindex and check again.

Without assigning the attribute to the attribute set, it will not be visible in the product edit form in the admin panel.

Comment: OK I've added the attribute to the 'Default' attribute set (group=Product Attributes), re-indexed, flushed all caches - attribute still not appearing in the admin product edit form

Comment: Please check which attribute set is being used to create product?

Comment: ok works for adding a new simple product (attribute appearing) but not editing an existing one … that normal? what if I want to view/edit this attribute value for lots of historical (existing) simple products ... ?

Comment: Select the products from **`catalog -> manage products`** grid, then select **`Update Attributes`** from the actions dropdown and click on button.

Comment: You will find the attribute in the next screeen. You can click on **Change** link and fill the updated value and save. (This solution will work only if you have to fill same value for all selected products)

Comment: OK I was editing a product which was in a different attribute set to the 'Default' attribute set (I can see it now). Thanks

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Any help regard, if move attribute to attribute set save button not functioning i mean save not work.

Comment: @Rathinam, do you see any JS error in the browser console? or Is there any log related to this in the **`var --> log`** folder?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Yes, i am getting js errro : https://snag.gy/Nmgn6p.jpg

Comment: @Rathinam, seems that you have messed up with some core functionality of Magento. Please check whether it may be helpful or not:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431225/javascript-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/js-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined-someone-please-tell-me-what-is-incorrect